# Getting error code -32000 (rlp: value size exceeds available input length) while sending raw matic transaction in C++

Tags: raw-transaction, polygon, sendrawtransaction, rlp

I use [this repo](https://github.com/Kidades/hwwallet) (as well as [this one](https://github.com/KingHodor/Ethereum-RLP)) to generate raw transaction and send it to the Polygon network through JSON-RPC in C++, but I get the error code -32000 (rlp: value size exceeds available input length).

```
TX tx;
tx.chainId = "0x25";
tx.to = "0x72a56b...";
tx.data = "0x310edb4d000000...";// around 600 bytes of data
tx.value = "0x00";
tx.gasLimit = "0xffff";
tx.gasPrice = "0x10";
tx.nonce = "0x361";
```

What can cause this problem?

Comment: I suggest implement the same in golang and check which field produces different values. Looks like this library is outdated but there was some change in RLP module recently

Comment: @Nulik I checked it with Ethereum specs, there was a bug in the repo code which I fixed, but I now get "Invalid sender" error from ` eth_sendRawTransaction`. Do you have any idea about this one?

Comment: most likely wrong chain ID when signing

Comment: if you are sending legacy transactions then it must be EIP155 signer type